# What does the acronym or shorthand "lg" mean?

Tags: symbols, taocp

What does "lg" mean in the following phrase?

"... we ignore the least significant lg *t* bits of *x* when referring to M<sub>*t*</sub>[*x*]." (Knuth, 2005, pp. 4-5).

From the context, it seems like "lg t" means "t -1" so that lg 2 would be 1 and lg 5 would be 4. That said, what is the strict meaning of "lg" here?

References

Knuth, D. E. (2005). The art of computer programming: Volume 1, fascicle 1 : MMIX, a RISC computer for the new millennium. Upper Saddle River, New Jersey: Addison-Wesley.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

lg means log to the base 2.

i.e. lg(4) = 2, lg(2) = 1.

Answer (score 7):

"lg" is commonly used to represent base 2 logarithms but this is a misuse is propagated in a few computer science texts.

Logarithm abbreviations are governed by standards. The abbreviation "lg" is reserved under DIN (DIN 1302) and ISO standards (ISO-31-11, ISO 80000-2) for a logarithm base 10. Since "lg" is widely used in other science and engineering fields in this manner, no one should use "lg" to refer to a base 2 logarithm.

The correct abbreviation for base 2 logarithm is logarithmus binaris (the binary logarithm) is "lb," though some Germans still use "ld" (for logarithmus dualis).

One of the most popular texts misusing the abbreviation (Cormen et alli: Introduction to Algorithms) commits several other mathematical sins (such as misusing "asymptotic") that make it more difficult for students to connect the material to their precalculus and calculus courses.

References:

1. [Wikipedia - Binary Logarithm: Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_logarithm#Notation)
2. [Guide for the Use of the International System of Units (SI) — NIST Special Publication 811, 2008 Edition — Second Printing](http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/sp811.pdf)
3. [Quantities and units – Part 2: Mathematical signs and symbols to be used in the natural sciences and technology](http://www.ise.ncsu.edu/jwilson/files/mathsigns.pdf)

Comment: Do you know what it means in the context that Knuth is using it in the quote from the question?

Comment: This is silly. Knuth holds more weight than some arbitrary IEEE "standard" paperweight.

Answer (score 3):

The quoted passage refers to Knuth Vol. 1 [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cC9M6.png)].  Section 1.2.2 of this monumental work is entitled "Numbers, Powers, and Logarithms".   Here's how Knuth explains his notation:

"One might expect that in computer work *binary logarithms* (to  the base 2) would be more useful, since most computers do binary arithmetic.  Actually, we will see that binary logarithms are indeed very useful, but not only for that reason; the reason is primarily that a computer algorithm often makes two-way branches.  Binary logarithms arise so frequently, it is wise to have a shorter notation for them.  Therefore we shall write [image], following a suggestion of Edward M. Reingold."

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cC9M6.png): Knuth, *The Art of Computer Programming*, third edition, Addison-Wesley, 1997.

Comment: Knuth published the first edition of Vol 1 in 1968.  The abbreviation lb for $\lg$ was (AFAIK) first mentioned in the blogosphere in 1994, causing one wag to comment "God help us if we let IUPAC or ANSI standardize mathematical notation..."

Comment: Randall C. Poe, in response to a question from Bernhard Seebass: "What's the definition of log, ln, lg, lb", sci.math, 1994.  Available https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/2WwCtiNvfJw.

Comment: ISO 31-11 was published in 1992, according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_31-11.

Comment: The DIN 1302 standard referenced by mirams (https://stackoverflow.com/users/2237671/mirams) is available for EUR 89.80 at https://www.din.de/en/getting-involved/standards-committees/natg/publications/wdc-beuth:din21:20122828.  AFAIK no German algorithmicist writes lb for $\lg$; and I wouldn't expect many German mathematicians to care overmuch about $\log_2$.

Answer (score 2):

Probably logarithm of t with base 2.